# excluding a value from a form drop down in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form drop down, that shows me all the emails in my User db table.

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:accessor_id, User.all,:email ,:email) %>
```

I want to exclude from this list the value of the current's user email, which I can find with with `current_user.email` (already defined and working)

I know I can achieve this via the following query:

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:accessor_id, User.select(:email).where("email !=?" , current_user.email),:email ,:email) %>
```

i wanted to know if it is possible to do this after User.all returned all of the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean something like

```
User.all.reject {|user| user == current_user}
```

or more precisely i would fetch all users somewhere in the controller

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

and use something like that in the form

```
<%= f.collection_select(:accessor_id, @users.reject {|user| user == current_user}.map(&:email)) %>
```

Comment: so after you return the query value. I know that I can do that at the query level

Comment: huh? that's not at the query level. what exactly do you want to know? your question is not super clear.

Comment: I am sorry. I wanted to know if there is an option to truncate the data after we perform the User.all vs. eliminating the data during the query. I guess it is better to do it during the query

Answer (score 3):

@phoet answer is correct, personally I would probably do this at database level anyhow, something along lines of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.all_without(excluded)
    where("id NOT IN (?)", excluded)
  end
end


<%= f.collection_select(:accessor_id, User.all_without([current_user]), :email ,:email) %>
```

try to keep the view 'clean' of the details, if possible

```
# and if you really do only want to pull email from the database, you can chain the query
User.all_without([current_user]).select(:email)
```

Comment: does your self.all_withoug goes in the model or in the controller ?

Comment: that is in the User model